# Django login function - TypeError: context must be a dict rather than Context

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-csrf

I'm working on a Django project. I'm having a problem with the login view. No matter what I try I keep getting a type error.

Here are the html template and login view:

**login.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load bootstrap_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <form role="form" method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
        <legend>Login</legend>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form| as_bootstrap }}
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
        </div>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**accounts/views.py**

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserLoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = auth.authenticate(email=request.POST.get('email'),
                                     password=request.POST.get('password'))

            if user is not None:
                auth.login(request, user)
                messages.error(request, "You have successfully logged in")
                return redirect(reverse('index'))
            else:
                form.add_error(None, "Your email or password was not recognised")

        else:
            form = UserLoginForm()

    args = {'form': form}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    return render(request, 'login.html', args)
```

When I attempt to navigate to login template from index on local server it returns an error:

> typeError: context must be a dict rather than Context.

Would someone please shed some light on this error, not been able to find a solution yet.

**Updated: full traceback**

```
Traceback:

File "/Users/Andrew/Documents/Code/code-institute-projects/stream-three/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/Andrew/Documents/Code/code-institute-projects/stream-three/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/Andrew/Documents/Code/code-institute-projects/stream-three/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/Andrew/Documents/Code/code-institute-projects/stream-three/movie_app/MovieApp_prj/accounts/views.py" in login
  117.     return render(request, 'login.html', args)

File "/Users/Andrew/Documents/Code/code-institute-projects/stream-three/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  30.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "/Users/Andrew/Documents/Code/code-institute-projects/stream-three/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  68.     return template.render(context, request)

File "/Users/Andrew/Documents/Code/code-institute-projects/stream-three/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  66.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/Users/Andrew/Documents/Code/code-institute-projects/stream-three/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  207.                     return self._render(context)

File "/Users/Andrew/Documents/Code/code-institute-projects/stream-three/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/Users/Andrew/Documents/Code/code-institute-projects/stream-three/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/Users/Andrew/Documents/Code/code-institute-projects/stream-three/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/Users/Andrew/Documents/Code/code-institute-projects/stream-three/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  177.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/Users/Andrew/Documents/Code/code-institute-projects/stream-three/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/Users/Andrew/Documents/Code/code-institute-projects/stream-three/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/Users/Andrew/Documents/Code/code-institute-projects/stream-three/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/Users/Andrew/Documents/Code/code-institute-projects/stream-three/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  72.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/Users/Andrew/Documents/Code/code-institute-projects/stream-three/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/Users/Andrew/Documents/Code/code-institute-projects/stream-three/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/Users/Andrew/Documents/Code/code-institute-projects/stream-three/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  1040.             output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)

File "/Users/Andrew/Documents/Code/code-institute-projects/stream-three/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in resolve
  736.                 new_obj = func(obj, *arg_vals)

File "/Users/Andrew/Documents/Code/code-institute-projects/stream-three/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_forms_bootstrap/templatetags/bootstrap_tags.py" in as_bootstrap
  28.     return template.render(c)

File "/Users/Andrew/Documents/Code/code-institute-projects/stream-three/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  64.         context = make_context(context, request, autoescape=self.backend.engine.autoescape)

File "/Users/Andrew/Documents/Code/code-institute-projects/stream-three/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/context.py" in make_context
  287.         raise TypeError('context must be a dict rather than %s.' % context.__class__.__name__)

Exception Type: TypeError at /login/
Exception Value: context must be a dict rather than Context.
```

Comment: Try removing the line `args.update(csrf(request))`...

Comment: try with context=args

Comment: The code you have shown doesn't use `Context` so shouldn't give that error. You might have to restart your server to make sure you're not running old code. If you include the full traceback in your question it might be clearer what the problem is. You can remove `args.update(csrf(request))` - you don't need to do anything for csrf in the view when you use `render`.

Comment: Could you post a traceback? As Alasdair mentioned there is no Context(dict) in the code so it would be difficult to diagnose where the issue is emitting from.

Comment: Added traceback. Tried removing the line and with context=args, still no luck...

Comment: Have you restarted the server as I suggested?

Comment: Yes, restarted the server still no luck.

Comment: There was something a miss in the environment, the code must have been conflicting with an old/new version and causing the strange error. Finally solved it. Thanks anyway :)